# How to show background in styled-components?

Tags: css, styled-components

In my react-app I cannot see the background/border style. What am I doing wrong?

This is what is looks like:

```
 <Flex>
        <Box
          bg="blue"
          css={{
            borderRadius: "4px"
          }}
        />
 </Flex>
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/0ov2xo7pkp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't the content in box. 
When you add any content, you will see the border radius and background color.
If you change like below, then you will see the background.

```
<Flex>
    <Box
       bg="blue"
       css={{
         borderRadius: "4px"
       }}
    >
       lorem texts
    </Box>
</Flex>
```

and you can specify

> width={1}

to make box will have full width.